# How do you mount a :mountable Rails Engine in a :full Engine and run migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have a mountable Rails Engine with its own models and namespaced tables (`MountableEngine`). I have another engine, a `--full` one, with its own schema (`FullEngine`). What I'd like is to include both of these engines into an actual app, but **only include the full engine**, i.e. `FullEngine` in the app's GemFile.

Is this possible? I haven't tried testing this in a skeleton Rails app, but in the `FullEngine`, I've included the mountable engine in its Gemfile, like so:

```
gem 'mountable_engine', path: "../my/path/mountable_engine"
```

But running the migrations in `FullEngine`, I get this error:

```
rake mountable_engine:install:migrations
Don't know how to build task 'mountable_engine:install:migrations'
```

The reason why I want the migrations to run in the `FullEngine` is that I want `FullEngine` to encapsulate the combined logic and functionality of the two engines, so that the actual app inherits it all by just including `FullEngine`

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions found on Pivotal Lab's blog here, [leave your migrations in your Rails engines](http://pivotallabs.com/leave-your-migrations-in-your-rails-engines/), which advises you to monkey patch the Rails::Engine class to append your engine's migration *paths* to the invoking app's migration path setup:

```
initializer :append_migrations do |app|
  unless app.root.to_s.match root.to_s
    app.config.paths["db/migrate"] += config.paths["db/migrate"].expanded
  end
end
```

So I'm not sure if the answer to my question is: "Yes, and that's a good idea to structure your engines that way"...but this monkey-patch at least allows all migrations to run from your dependent engines.